# Chamar um formulário dependendo dos inputs radio selecionados

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap-3

Tenho dois campos inputs do tipo radio dependendo da combinação de escolhas eu quero chamar um formulário diferente para cada caso, exemplo.

```
<label>SELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO</label>
 <form>
  <label><input value="A" name="opcao" type="radio">opcao A</label> 
  <label><input value="B" name="opcao" type="radio">opcao B</label>
  <label><input value="C" name="opcao2" type="radio">opcao C</label> 
  <label><input value="D" name="opcao2" type="radio">opcao D</label> 
 </form>
```

Se selecionar a opção A junto com a C aparecer um formulário, se selecionar A com D aparecer outro, B com C outro e B com D outro.

Como faria isso estou enrolado na parte de JavaScript Sei nem por onde começar, quero fazer isso sem ter que atualizar a pagina.

Comment: Com "chamar um formulario diferente" signifca que action do form vai mudar, ou vai exibir outro form, outros campos..não ficou muito claro pra mim.

Comment: Vai adicionar outros campos em baixo dos radios e cada combinação de radios chamar campos diferentes no formulário.

Comment: Bom acredito que seja algo parecido com isso: https://jsfiddle.net/Showva/bzq7gae1/

Comment: se clicar primeiro na opção D ou C e depois na opção A ou B não carrega o form.

Comment: modifiquei pra fazer os radios ficarem selecionados

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(event) {
        var option1 = $('input[name="opcao"]').filter(':checked').val();
        var option2 = $('input[name="opcao2"]').filter(':checked').val();
        getForm(option1, option2)

    });

    // Traz o form com ajax
    function getForm(option1, option2){
        console.log(option1);
        console.log(option2);

        if ( (option1 == 'A') && (option2 == 'C') ) {
            // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
        }

        if ( (option1 === 'A' && option2 === 'D') ) {
            // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
        }

        if ( (option1 === 'B' && option2 === 'C') ) {
            // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
        }

        if ( (option1 === 'B' && option2 === 'D') ) {
            // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
        }
    }

});
```

Você pode fazer chamadas ajax de acordo com o valor do input.

Comment: Como faz essa chamada com ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Para combinar todos os casos possíveis fiz assim:

```js
 var a="";
  var a2="";
  var a3="";
  var z="";
  $(window).load(function(){
     $('.opcao').on('change', function() {
        a +=(this.checked ? this.value : '');     
        var n = a.length;
        if (n>2){
            a2 = a.substring(0, 1);
            a = a.substring(1, 3);
        }

        if ((a=="AB")||(a=="BA")||(a=="CD")||(a=="DC")){
            a3 =(this.checked ? this.value : '');
            a=a2+a3;
            z=(this.checked ? this.value : '');
            if (z=="A"){
               document.getElementById("opcao1").checked = true;
               document.getElementById("opcao2").checked = false;
            }else if (z=="B"){
               document.getElementById("opcao1").checked = false;
               document.getElementById("opcao2").checked = true;
            }else if (z=="C"){
               document.getElementById("opcao3").checked = true;
               document.getElementById("opcao4").checked = false;
            }else if (z=="D"){
               document.getElementById("opcao3").checked = false;
               document.getElementById("opcao4").checked = true;
            }
         }

         if ((a=="AC")||(a=="CA")){
             document.getElementById('tab1').style.display="block"; 
             document.getElementById('tab2').style.display="none";
             document.getElementById('tab3').style.display="none";
             document.getElementById('tab4').style.display="none";
         }else if ((a=="AD")||(a=="DA")){
             document.getElementById('tab1').style.display="none"; 
             document.getElementById('tab2').style.display="block";
             document.getElementById('tab3').style.display="none";
             document.getElementById('tab4').style.display="none";
         }else if ((a=="BC")||(a=="CB")){
             document.getElementById('tab1').style.display="none"; 
             document.getElementById('tab2').style.display="none";
             document.getElementById('tab3').style.display="block";
             document.getElementById('tab4').style.display="none";
         }else if ((a=="BD")||(a=="DB")){
             document.getElementById('tab1').style.display="none"; 
             document.getElementById('tab2').style.display="none";
             document.getElementById('tab3').style.display="none";
             document.getElementById('tab4').style.display="block";     
         }else{
             document.getElementById('tab1').style.display="none"; 
             document.getElementById('tab2').style.display="none";
             document.getElementById('tab3').style.display="none";
             document.getElementById('tab4').style.display="none";
         }

    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form name="meuFormulario">
       <label>SELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO</label> 
       <label><input value="A" name="opcao" class="opcao" id="opcao1" type="radio">opcao A</label> 
       <label><input value="B" name="opcao" class="opcao" id="opcao2" type="radio">opcao B</label><br>
       <label>SELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO</label> 
       <label><input value="C" name="opcao2" class="opcao" id="opcao3" type="radio">opcao C</label> 
        <label><input value="D" name="opcao2" class="opcao" id="opcao4" type="radio">opcao D</label> 
     </form> 
</div>

<div>
<div id="tab1" style="display: none;">
    <p>form A C</p>     
</div>
<div id="tab2" style="display: none;">
    <p>form A D</p>
</div>
<div id="tab3" style="display: none;">
    <p>form B C</p>
</div>
<div id="tab4" style="display: none;">
    <p>form B D</p>
</div>
```

> answered solution ? enjoy : Let's work more

Comment: Esta certo so que quando o formulario aparece os radios são deselecionados, tem como eles continuar selecionados?